# Make Label Dynamic on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, label

how can I make the entry of a Label field in Excel Dynamic? 
What I want is, when I open up the excel file my username will show up on the dynamic label field. on a Excel 5.0 Dialog.

[image]

Comment: You can make it dynamic by binding it to an event. For example Workbook_Open or Worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to bind the value to username and Workbook_Open event. Just make sure you have the right name in "Label 1".

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("YourSheetName").Shapes("Label 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Environ("Username")
End Sub
```

Place it in VBA.Project ThisWorkbook

This where you find the name of the label:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! how do I find out what the name of the label is? sorry I'm completely new to VBA

Comment: See edit. Also I would recommend in future only using ActiveX controls as they bring function more nicely with VBA. Well at least in cases where you want to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in the sheet specific module - this will dynamically change `Label 1`'s caption whenever something on the worksheet changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Label 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```